# Why are all Laplacian eigenfunctions on the square obtained by separation of variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let our domain $\Omega = (0,2\pi)\times(0,2\pi)$ be a square with sides parallel to the axes.

Consider the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem $\Delta u+\lambda u=0$ with Dirichlet boundary condition $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$. It is known that separation of variables yields the solutions, for example in [these lecture notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~canzani/math253/Lecture3.pdf).

My question: Why are *all* solutions given this way? Why doesn't there exist a solution that can't be obtained by separation of variables?

(Of course, a linear combination of solutions obtained by separation of variables might not have separated variables, but I'm asking why there isn't something other than those basic solutions and their linear combinations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a partial differential operator $L$ with a domain $D_L\,$, this is always the case whenever $L$ admits separation of variables on $D_L$. The variables are to be separated successively one-by-one. Your example of $L=\Delta$ on $D_L=H^1_0(\Omega)\cap 
H^2(\Omega)$, with $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ being a square, is just the simplest instance of such successive separation of variables. It is absolutely unimportant what variable shall one start with. Let it be $x$. In this case, consider the Sturm-Liouville problem
$$
\begin{cases}
X''=\mu X,\;x\in (0,2\pi),\\
X(0)=X(2\pi)=0
\end{cases} \quad \Rightarrow\quad 
\begin{cases}
X_j(x)=\sin{\frac{jx}{2}}\,,\\
\mu_j=-\frac{j^2}{4}\,,\;j\geqslant 1. 
\end{cases} 
$$
Due to the widely known fact that $\{X_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthogonal basis in 
$L^2(0,2\pi)$, every eigenfunction $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$, *i.e.*, any nontrivial solution 
$Lu+\lambda u=0,\;u\in D_L\,$, can be developed into Fourier series
$$
u(x,y)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}Y_j(y)X_j(x), \quad Y_j(y)=\frac{(u,X_j)}{\|X_j\|^2}
=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}u(x,y)\sin{\frac{jx}{2}}dx,\;\,j\geqslant 1.
$$
Applying the habitual multiplying and integrating by parts, one readily gets
BVPs for the Fourier coefficints $Y_j\,$, namely,
$$
\begin{cases}
Y_j''+\Bigl(\lambda-\frac{j^2}{4}\Bigr)Y_j=0,\;y\in (0,2\pi),\\
Y_j(0)=Y_j(2\pi)=0,\quad j\geqslant 1.
\end{cases} \tag{1}
$$
It is clear that nontrivial solutions $Y_j$ of BVP $(1)$ exist if only
$$
\lambda-\frac{j^2}{4}=\frac{k^2}{4}\,,\quad j\geqslant 1,\;k\geqslant 1.
$$
Hence every nontrivial solution $Lu+\lambda u=0,\;u\in D_L\,$, is of the form
$$
u_{jk}(x,y)=\sin{\frac{jx}{2}}\sin{\frac{ky}{2}}, \quad 
\lambda_{jk}=\frac{j^2}{4}+\frac{k^2}{4}\,,\;\;\,j,k\geqslant 1,
$$
except for certain eigenvalues $\lambda$ which admit multiple representation
$$
-4\lambda=j_1^2+k_1^2=\dots=j_N^2+k_N^2,\quad N=N(\lambda)\geqslant 1,$$
where $N(\lambda)$ denotes a geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$. Here is the list of the first 24 multiple eigenvalues, *i.e.*,  with geometric multiplicities $N(\lambda)\geqslant 2\,$:
$$
\begin{align}
-4\lambda=50 = 1^2 + 7^2 = 5^2 + 5^2,\\
-4\lambda=65 = 1^2 + 8^2 = 4^2 + 7^2,\\
-4\lambda=85 = 2^2 + 9^2 = 6^2 + 7^2,\\
-4\lambda=125 = 2^2 + 11^2 = 5^2 + 10^2,\\
-4\lambda=130 = 3^2 + 11^2 = 7^2 + 9^2,\\
-4\lambda=145 = 1^2 + 12^2 = 8^2 + 9^2,\\
-4\lambda=170 = 1^2 + 13^2 = 7^2 + 11^2,\\
-4\lambda=185 = 4^2 + 13^2 = 8^2 + 11^2,\\
-4\lambda=200 = 2^2 + 14^2 = 10^2 + 10^2,\\
-4\lambda=205 = 3^2 + 14^2 = 6^2 + 13^2,\\
-4\lambda=221 = 5^2 + 14^2 = 10^2 + 11^2,\\
-4\lambda=250 = 5^2 + 15^2 = 9^2 + 13^2,\\
-4\lambda=260 = 2^2 + 16^2 = 8^2 + 14^2,\\
-4\lambda=265 = 3^2 + 16^2 = 11^2 + 12^2,\\
-4\lambda=290 = 1^2 + 17^2 = 11^2 + 13^2,\\
-4\lambda=305 = 4^2 + 17^2 = 7^2 + 16^2,\\
-4\lambda=325 = 1^2 + 18^2 = 6^2 + 17^2 = 10^2 + 15^2,\\
-4\lambda=338 = 7^2 + 17^2 = 13^2 + 13^2,\\
-4\lambda=340 = 4^2 + 18^2 = 12^2 + 14^2,\\
-4\lambda=365 = 2^2 + 19^2 = 13^2 + 14^2,\\
-4\lambda=370 = 3^2 + 19^2 = 9^2 + 17^2,\\
-4\lambda=377 = 4^2 + 19^2 = 11^2 + 16^2,\\
-4\lambda=410 = 7^2 + 19^2 = 11^2 + 17^2,\\
-4\lambda=425 = 5^2 + 20^2 = 8^2 + 19^2 = 13^2 + 16^2.
\end{align}
$$
Since all eigenfunctions $u_{jk}$ are pairwise orthogonal, for every particular eigenvalue $\lambda$, a Fourier series for solution corresponding to this $\lambda$
degenerates into a finite sum
$$
u(x,y)=\sum_{r=1}^{N(\lambda)}c_r(j,k)u_{jk}(x,y).
$$

Comment: You say that  any eigenfunction can be developed as $\sum Y_jX_j $. The questions was: why is that true?

Comment: @words that end in GRY: Explanation added. Every eigenfunction $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ can be developed as $u=\sum Y_jX_j$ due to the widely known fact that $\{X_j\}$ is an orthogonal basis in $L^2(0,2\pi)$, and even in $H^1_0(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: The notation $H_i^n(\Omega)$ is unfamiliar to me. What does that one mean? Is that saying $u$ has continuous first and second order partial derivatives?

Answer (score 3):

Because with separation of variables we find enough eigenfunctions $$\psi_{jk}(x,y)=\sin \frac{jx}{2} \sin \frac{ky}{2}$$ so that their linear span is dense in $H^1_0$. Indeed, suppose there is a substantially new eigenfunction $\phi$, i.e., not a linear combination of known ones. Recall that  distinct eigenspaces of $\Delta$ are mutually orthogonal in $H^1$. So, if the eigenvalue of $\phi$ is different from known eigenvalues $\lambda_{jk}$, then $\phi \perp \{\psi_{jk}\}$. Hence, the span of $\{\psi_{jk}\}$ is not dense; a contradiction.

If  $\phi$ belongs to an eigenspace we know, but is not a linear combination of eigenfunctions we know, that also implies that the span of $\{\psi_{jk}\}$ is not dense: it is not even dense in that eigenspace.

Comment: I don't understand something in your answer. It is clear that if $\operatorname{Span}\left\{\psi_{jk}\right\}$ is dense in $H^1_0$ then these are all the solutions. But why is it dense to begin with?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein This is the issue of completeness of trigonometric series, which also arises on an interval. One often solves it with Stone-Weierstrass. Let's identify all boundary points into one, i.e., use one-point compactification of the domain. Sines form an algebra that separates points. Throw in a constant, and Stone-Weierstrass applies: every continuous function $f$ that is constant on the boundary can be approximated by sines plus a constant. But that additional constant can be taken to be zero when $f$ vanishes on the boundary.

Comment: Could someone give me a nice reference in which one proves that this set of eigenfunctions is dense in $H_{0}^{1}$?